# My app restarted itself, log shows ChimeraModuleLdr: Module config changed, forcing restart due to module

Tags: android

I was testing my app and I saw it restart itself, was really weird. I looked and looked on the logs and I couldn't find anything odd except for this line `ChimeraModuleLdr: Module config changed, forcing restart due to module`. This is on a Pixel XL with Oreo.

Here are the last few lines of the log and the start up of the app after it was killed.

```
10-18 22:49:31.262  8379  8379 I ChimeraModuleLdr: Module config changed, forcing restart due to module 
10-18 22:49:31.262  8379  8379 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 8379 SIG: 9
--------- beginning of main
10-18 22:49:31.641 13717 13717 I MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
10-18 22:49:31.641 13717 13717 I MultiDex: install
10-18 22:49:31.641 13717 13717 I MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
```

Any idea about what triggered this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the ***ChimeraModule*** (or *Dynamite*) is the **dynamic module loading system used by the Google Play Services** (more details [here](https://blogs.fsfe.org/larma/2017/signal-backdoors/)).

I guess that, if your app is using a specific module from the Google Play Services, **when that specific module is updated your app is restarted** as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: do you know if I disable the play store updates, the ChimeraModule will stop updating the packages?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @bonnyz already said, I fixed it by removing all references to the libraries updated by the module, in my case the android vision library.

Answer (score 0):

Adding further,
In context of Xamarin Forms project, the error you describe was caused by the Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps V4 package.  reverting to V3.x.x solved the problem for me.

Comment: Check app manifest file is more then one app launcer entry in any activity?