# How to handle 'Module config changed, forcing restart due to module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite' in a QT app?

Tags: android, qt, google-play-services

As far as I can understand from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46865465/my-app-restarted-itself-log-shows-chimeramoduleldr-module-config-changed-forc), there is some `ChimeraModule` module that periodically closes my app when I start it on a clean emulator. I have `onApplicationStateChanged` QT event handler that saves the app state to a file, but it is not called in this case, so the app state is lost.

What is the right point to save my data in this case?

App logs contains the following:

```
D MyApp : onApplicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationActive)
...
I ChimeraModuleLdr: Module config changed, forcing restart due to module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite
I Process : Sending signal. PID: 7442 SIG: 9
```

When I switch to another app (or deactivate the app) there is also

```
D MyApp : onApplicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationInactive)
D MyApp : onApplicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationSuspended)
```

in the logs and the app state is saved.